# Custom C++ stream for custom type

Tags: c++, c++11, stream

I've read about custom streams for C++ but it seems that generally people inherit from `std::streambuf`, `std::istream`, and `std::ostream`. By inspecting those type's declarations it becomes clear that these are meant for characters:

```
typedef basic_streambuf<char>        streambuf;
```

[The docs](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/) confirm this:

> Input stream objects can read and interpret input from sequences of
>   characters.

Obviously, that makes sense. I'm wondering what would be the correct way of implementing a stream for other types. I do not want to allow text but other forms of binary input/output (I have specific formats). The obvious step seems to be to inherit the `basic` variants of the above (`basic_streambuf`, `basic_istream`, and `basic_ostream`) and use whatever type I see fit as the template parameter. I failed to find confirmation that this would be the right procedure. So, is it?

Edit for clarification: I have a class called Segment. These streams will send/receive segments and only segments over a WiFi connection as these are used in the communication protocol. Sending anything else would break the protocol. This means that the stream cannot support other types.

Comment: The insertion/extraction operators (`operator<<`/`operator>>`) will perform the conversion from various standard types to the stream's character type. The `streambuf` for that stream can perform the formatting using those characters.

Comment: Yes, but like I said, I do not want the streams to accept text, just a very specific set of types

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you want?

Comment: Well, I have a class called `Segment`. These streams will send/receive segments and only segments over a WiFi connection as these are used in the communication protocol. Sending anything else would break the protocol

Comment: You'd have to specialize `basic_streambuf`, `basic_istream` and `basic_ostream` for `Segment`.

Comment: You may take a look on basic_streambuf<wchar_t> in a modern STL implementation (I've just looked into `/usr/include/c++/5/iosfwd` from GCC5, I'm sure other modern compilers also have it)

Comment: Well, I'm not completely understand your question. You're looking for a non-`char` implementation of stream-related machinery. Here's one. Likely you could share most of the implementation with the generic one, but surely you need to provide your own implementation when it's needed

Comment: I see. Please read the previous comments. I explain what I want. I'll also edit the question to include the details.

Comment: Ok, may I ask what's the _exact_ goal to follow/re-use the standard stream* classes?

Comment: Nothing particular, to be honest. I'm just considering alternatives. To be honest I already have a stub implementation which does not use standard streams. Obviously, if possible, I'd like to conform to the standards as much as possible, but it's not a requirement. Right now I have read/write methods, and so far it seems best to stick with it

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question in terms of inheriting from `std::basic_*` with non-`char` types. But following the comments and given your application, I am questioning the need to reimplement the whole standard stream machinery for your `Segment` type, when you can simply define a class with a stream operator:

```
class SegmentStream
{
public:

    SegmentStream& operator<< ( const Segment& s );
}
```

Better yet you could clarify your code by defining methods `send` and `recv` instead of `>>, <<`.
Or perhaps you could explain why this would not be sufficient and why you specifically want to use standard streams?

Comment: Totally agree with you. As I mentioned in the comments I've just been looking at design alternatives. Confirming to the standard streams seemed like an obvious alternative, as it would be writeable to file, string, and so on in one go. Currently my implementation is using read/write methods and I think I'll leave this issue pending